WP_Query based on value in array in meta field
I am trying to perform a WP Query using the value within an array to exclude certain rows.
I have an event table with a event_status field that is type 'Radio Button' setup as follows.
0 : Provisional
1 : Active
2 : Postponed
3 : Cancelled

I have the return value set to Both.
Therefore when I use get_field('event_status') I get returned the following.
[24-Nov-2024 14:35:27 UTC] {"value":"0","label":"Provisional"}
What I'm looking to do is query only rows where the label is something other than Provisional.
Currently the query is
$events = new WP_Query(Array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'post_type' => "event",
    'meta_key' => 'event_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'date_clause' => array(
            'key' => 'event_date',
            'compare' => '>=',
            'value' => $today->format('Ymd'),
            'type' => 'DATE',
        ),
        'status_clause' => array(
            'key' => 'event_status',
            'compare' => '!=',
            'value' => 'Provisional'
        )
    )
));

which I know isn't correct.
I have trawled the web but can't find anything specific to allow searching based on a value inside a returned array using the array element (ie 'label' == 'Provisional')
Anyone able to help please?

You can just query for value not equal to 0(value) instead of the label(Provisional)
$events = new WP_Query(array(
'posts_per_page' => 3,
'post_type' => "event",
'meta_key' => 'event_date',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'ASC',
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    'date_clause' => array(
        'key' => 'event_date',
        'compare' => '>=',
        'value' => $today->format('Ymd'),
        'type' => 'DATE',
    ),
    'status_clause' => array(
        'key' => 'event_status',
        'compare' => '!=',
        'value' => '0'  // Looking for the value, not the label
    )
)));

I tested locally without the date_clause as I didn't add an event_date field and it works fine.

Thanks, I've tested it and it works, however I still don't know why. I'm guessing that on the DB the value (0) is stored in the row and it's ACF that's adding the label information when performing a get_field.
Does that sound plausible?

It's because of how you have setup the radio buttons.
0 : Provisional.
1 : Active.
2 : Postponed.
3 : Cancelled
Instead if you had set it up like below, both the value and label would have been the same.
Provisional.
Active
Postponed
Cancelled

OK I see now, thanks.
